# Change first occurrence of Nan in a specific DataFrame row to a new value

Tags: pandas

I have just started learning Pandas.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

I have an existing DataFrame, `opis`, which looks like this:

```
                    mc_1  mc_2  mc_3  mc_4  mc_5
   opi
   joe.blow          539   544   545   NaN   NaN
   john.doe          222   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   jane.doe          333   555   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Given an `opi` and a `new_value`, I want to replace the first occurrence of Nan in the row with the `new_value`.

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
my_opi = 'joe.blow'
new_value = 99999

for idx, value in enumerate(opis.loc[my_opi]):
    if pd.isnull(value):
        opis.loc[my_opi][idx] = new_value
        break
```

Thanks in advance.

Expected output

```
                  mc_1  mc_2  mc_3  mc_4  mc_5  
opi  
joe.blow          539   544   545  9999   NaN 
john.doe          222   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
jane.doe          333   555   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is a bug in master will fillna and a limit (fixed shortly), but you can do this.

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame(dict(mc_1 = [539,222,333],mc_2=[544,np.nan,555],mc_3=[545,np.nan,np.nan],mc_4=np.nan,mc_5=np.nan),index=['joe.blow','john.doe','jane.doe'])

In [10]: df[df.isnull() & (df.isnull().cumsum()<=1)] = 9999

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
          mc_1  mc_2  mc_3  mc_4  mc_5
joe.blow   539   544   545  9999  9999
john.doe   222  9999  9999   NaN   NaN
jane.doe   333   555   NaN   NaN   NaN

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

In 0.14 you can do

```
df.fillna(9999,limit=1)
```

This will work, but will raise an error if all the value are valid in that row.
You could catch it, or test the result of the `get_loc` to see if it exceeds the number
of columns.

```
row = 'joe.blow'

In [15]: df.ix[row,df.columns.get_loc(df.loc[row].last_valid_index())+1] = 999

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
          mc_1  mc_2  mc_3  mc_4  mc_5
joe.blow   539   544   545   999   NaN
john.doe   222   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
jane.doe   333   555   NaN   NaN   NaN

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff. I was really looking to only replace the first occurrence of a NaN in a **specific** row. I did see the `df.fillna()` in the documentation but it performs the replacement on **all** rows not one specific row.

Comment: pls put up your expected output then

Comment: `mc_1  mc_2  mc_3  mc_4  mc_5`
    `opi`
    `joe.blow          539   544   545  9999   NaN`
    `john.doe          222   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN`
    `jane.doe          333   555   NaN   NaN   NaN`

Comment: I'm trying to. I am putting four spaces before each line of the code and it is not working in the comments. Thanks for your patience I will figure this out soon.

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/YyFrFREH I gave up trying to use the mini-Markdown so I pasted my results in that link. I hope this isn't inconvenient.

Comment: posted an answer for you

Comment: Thank you sir! Things are starting to come together.